# Python checkbox variable to use in different class

Tags: python

I want to use the value of the checkbox inside a class in a different class, how do I do this?

```
class test1(Frame):
    def __init__(mons, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(mons, master)    

        Z1 = LabelFrame(mons.master, bg="#262526")
        Z1.place(x=125,y=325)
        mons.test1= IntVar(value=0)
        mons.test2= IntVar(value=0)
        mons.testt = customtkinter.CTkCheckBox(Z1, text="Test", variable=mons.test1, onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
        mons.top.grid()

class test:
    def classtest(mons):   
        if mons.test1.get == 1:
           print("yessss")
```

Comment: first you would have to use `self.` to access it outside function.

Comment: better assign `command=` to `CTkCheckBox` and send value as parameter.

Comment: better use name `self` instead of `mons` because nobody will know what is `mons`

Comment: all depends how you use function `classtest`. If you use it inside `test1` then you could use `def classtest(self, other_object): if other_object.get() == 1:...` and use it inside `test1 as `instance = test()` `instance.classtest(self)`. Or if you use it outside class `test1` then first you have to create `frame = test1()` and later `instance = test()` and `instance.classtest(frame)`

Comment: Sorunumu çözdüm hepinize çok teşekkür ederim.